# Use access token generated from one wso2 identity server to access an api registered in another wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, federated-identity, ws-federation, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

My goal to use access token which is created by wso2_identity_server1 for User1 which is existing only in wso2_identity_server1 to access a spring boot api which is registered with wso2_identity_server2 as service_provider2 through oauth2.
That mean in step -

1. Use service_provider1 to get access token for a user1 who only exist wso2_identity_server1
2. Use this access token to access api which is registered as service_provider2 in wso2_identity_server2.

Any help/examples will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register a OAuth service provider via the management console of WSO2 Identity Server and get client_id and client secret. To know about how to configure a OAuth service provider, refer to this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+Inbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider#ConfiguringInboundAuthenticationforaServiceProvider-OauthOpenIDConfiguringinboundauthenticationwithOAuth/OpenIDConnect)

Once you configured an OAuth service provider, you can use any of the following grants and obtain access_token.

1. authorization code grant
2. implicit flow
3. password grant
4. client_credentials grant

You can refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/generating-access-tokens-using-wso2-identity-server-4d8c084a3bf5) to get to know about how to get access tokens using with commands

You can refer to this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/OAuth+2.0+with+WSO2+Playground) related to samples  to try out also

Comment: It will work only for when i want to access api in the same wso2 idenity server. I want to get access token from one identity server and use it to access restful api which is registered in another wso2 identity server. I guess the idea is around identity federation but i want it for restful api. All the documentation provided in wso2 is based on browser support and redirection.

Comment: You can use JWT bearer grant. Refer to this document: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+JWT+Grant+Type. You can't directly use the access_token obtained by a IDP to invoke the api protected by another IDP. You can get JWT assertion from the trusted IDP and use the jwt-grant type and get a new access token from the Identity Server. Then you can use the access token to invoke the api registered in the same identity server.